# Pade' approximation

Tags: plotting, physics

Do you know how to enter this equation in Mathematica? It is Pade approximation, Values of p(2,..,7) are also given.
Is it just simply writing this in Mathematica? or should I do something else?

Comment: Please include Mathematica code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @Syed I haven't. there is `PadeApproximant` in mathematica. but I don't know how to fit this formula to that.

Comment: Do you want to find an approximation to $\theta$ at the point $T_{\text{eff}}$ = <some value> ?

Comment: @Syed I suppose so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function posted can be expressed exactly as an order [4/3]  Padé approximant about `Teff=0`.

Sometimes when defining a function with a lot of numeric parameters, it is easier to put in symbolic values `{p[2],p[3],...,p[7]}` first to confirm the function is defined correctly:

```
pSymbols = Array[p, 6, 2];
```

Your function sort of looks like $$\frac{k T_{eff}}{1- k T_{eff}\left(\frac{\mathrm{even \: P \: stuff}}{\mathrm{odd \:P \:stuff}}\right)}$$ Notice there's a pattern in the even and odd $P$ parts in the denominator of your function (there's probably a neater way to write this with `Nest` or `Fold`, I just haven't been able to figure it out yet). In this case, it probably would be easier just to write out the denominator by hand, but this makes sense to do here since there is a clear pattern:

```
evenPStuff = pSymbols[[-2]];
Do[
 evenPStuff *= k*Teff;
 evenPStuff += i;
 , 
{i, pSymbols[[1 ;; -3 ;; 2]] // Reverse}
 ]

oddPStuff = pSymbols[[-1]];
Do[
 oddPStuff *= k*Teff;
 oddPStuff += i;
, 
{i, pSymbols[[2 ;; -3 ;; 2]] // Reverse}
 ]
oddPStuff *= k*Teff;
oddPStuff += 1;
```

we can now neatly define $\theta$ (with symbolic values for the parameters $P_n$) as a function of $T_{eff}$ (pasting the output with the symbols as a screenshot so it's easier to look at):

```
\[Theta]Symbolic[Teff_] = (k*Teff)/(1 - k*Teff*(evenPStuff/oddPStuff))
```

[image]

Now let's take the order [4,3] Padé approximant about `Teff=0` of `\[Theta]Symbolic[Teff]`:

```
pade43 = PadeApproximant[\[Theta]Symbolic[Teff], {Teff, 0, {4, 3}}];
pade43 // Numerator // Expand
pade43 // Denominator // Expand
```

> `k Teff + k^2 Teff^2 p[3] + k^3 Teff^3 p[5] + k^4 Teff^4 p[7]`

> `1 - k Teff p[2] + k Teff p[3] - k^2 Teff^2 p[4] + k^2 Teff^2 p[5] -  k^3 Teff^3 p[6] + k^3 Teff^3 p[7]`

And we see this is indeed the same as `\[Theta]Symbolic[Teff]`:

```
pade43 == \[Theta]Symbolic[Teff] //Simplify
```

> `True`

We can also now plug in our numerical parameter values. We can plug them into `pade43` since we know it's the same as `\[Theta]Symbolic[Teff]` but has a nicer looking form:

```
pVals = {-5.9357*10^-2, 2.0165*10^-1, 1.0404*10^-3, 
   2.7621*10^-3, -9.1653*10^-6, 9.8305*10^-7};
\[Theta][Teff_] = pade43 /. AssociationThread[pSymbols -> pVals]
```

> `(k Teff + 0.20165 k^2 Teff^2 + 0.0027621 k^3 Teff^3 +  9.8305*10^-7 k^4 Teff^4)/(1 + 0.261007 k Teff +  0.0017217 k^2 Teff^2 + 0.0000101484 k^3 Teff^3)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your invaluable response. 
so if i just enter the last line:  `(k Teff + 0.20165 k^2 Teff^2 + 0.0027621 k^3 Teff^3 +  9.8305*10^-7 k^4 Teff^4)/(1 + 0.261007 k Teff +  0.0017217 k^2 Teff^2 + 0.0000101484 k^3 Teff^3)`
in my code, that would be enough?

Comment: @lia Yes (if all that you need to do is enter a definition for `\[Theta][Teff]` )

Comment: ok Thanks a lot for your time